# What to do when `addrinfo::ai_addrlen` is larger than `sizeof(struct sockaddr)`?

Tags: c, sockets

I have code that should check all addresses found by `getaddrinfo` and store the first one with the supported protocol in a `sockaddr` typed variable. However, it just happens that the `addrinfo::ai_addrlen` field is greater than `sizeof(struct sockaddr)`, so I can't just store it on stack, or can I? What is the correct thing to do here, copy `sizeof(struct sockaddr)` bytes of memory and ignore the rest, or to allocate the `struct sockaddr` instance on heap with the size `addrinfo::ai_addrlen`?

Comment: `addrinfo::ai_addrlen` is no valid C

Comment: @glglgl C has no notation for specifying qualified field names.

Answer (score 4):

Normally you don't copy the `ai_addr` member at all; you use it immediately as an argument to pass to `bind`, `connect`, or `getnameinfo`. If you do want to copy it, an object of type `struct sockaddr_storage` is appropriate, but this is generally bad practice. This is all a historical mess and a large part of the purpose of `getaddrinfo` is to avoid the historical mess by not declaring such types yourself.

Comment: I'm using this address to send UDP datagrams to, but not at the point where my `addrinfo` instance is reachable. What is the correct thing to do in this case?

Comment: Actually, nevermind that, I can just `connect` the socket anyway. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the family field you can cast `addrinfo::ai_addr` to `sockaddr_in` or `sockaddr_in6` and then sizeof will match. Otherwise you can just write `addrinfo::ai_addrlen` bytes starting at `addrinfo::ai_addr`.